# Is select/poll keep checking for data during wait or just check once when data available?

Tags: select, networking

when use select/poll , are they continuously checking for data in a loop 
 , Or just sleep and wake up until data is available

Comment: Who are "they" ? What does "select/poll" refer to?

Comment: @embert They are extremely well-known networking system calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They block until an event occurs or the timeout expires. No looping,